# Deleting one list from another

Tags: list, sml

I'm trying to write a program that deletes the list1 if it's in list2.

E.g

```
delete [1,2] [1,2,3,4]
  => [3,4]
```

I'm very close to solving it, but my code only removes the head of the first list from the second list, so...

```
delete [1,2] [1,2,3,4]
  => [2,3,4]
```

If anyone could help, that would be great :)

```
fun delete (hd1::tl1) [] = []
  | delete (hd1::tl1) (hd2::tl2) = 
      if hd1 = hd2 then delete (hd1::tl1) tl2 else hd2::delete(hd1::tl1) tl2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine whether the *entire* first list is the start of the second list.

And you want to build on what you did before - when you're studying, it is often the case that you've recently done something useful.

Given a function `start` that determines whether one list is the start of another, you can write

```
fun delete xs ys = if start xs ys
                   then <...>
                   else (hd ys) :: (delete xs (tl ys))
```

The interesting part is left as an exercise (you have almost certainly seen library functions that can be used).

Comment: Thanks very much. I actually had created a start function  a few days prior to trying this so ended up using it.

Comment: @ChrisMulheron I knew that. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Take the disjunction between the lists;

```
A-[1,2]B-[1,2,3,4] list(set(A) - set(B)) which returns [3,4]
```

then listcomprehension;

```
diff = [3,4] [x for x in B if x not in diff]
```